# I have enough stock for a product (woocommerce) but in cart it is showing out of stock

Tags: woocommerce

I am facing a unusual problem in woocommerce. I have enough stock for a particular simple product but when testing it for checkout. Woocommerce is showing out of stock message and asking be to come back after so on time and try again.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Main issue is...91 in stock (a simple product), when trying to purchase this product showing out of stock message and asking to come back after some time.

wordpress version 4.7.3 woocommerce version 3.0.5

Comment: Can you post the exact message?

Comment: Sorry, we do not have enough "XYZ" in stock to fulfill your order right now. Please try again in 10080 minutes or edit your cart and try again. We apologise for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: Woocommerce version is 2.6.14. I have not updated the plugin

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the issue. It was coming due to excessive on hold orders (for that particular product) i.e hold stock.

Thank you very much for your time and patience :)